# Running local node verison different than global with gulp and node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

I have a project that is using node npm and gulp. When we build the project node 5 is installed in the local directory and runs npm install (compiling all node modules agains node v5) I globally have node version 7 installed.

We have a gulp task that uses node-sass which is compiled against v5 but when I try to run the task it uses the global version and node-sass errors out out "Missing binding"

How can I run it using the local version of node?

Comment: In the gulpfile, are you `require`-ing node-sass? If you are, it should be pulling from the local node_modules packages, unless you created a symlink via `npm link node-sass`. If you are not `require`-ing the package, then that would be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is very helpful for managing and switching between multiple versions of node, including your globally installed packages.

Comment: Thanks will look into it. Was hoping there was something a bit simpler that I could run as an npm script or simliar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to automate it, you could just add the console command to use the needed version via nvm within your gulp task.
e.g. "nvm install v5.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon @dmfay's answer, you should have node 5 installed (via nvm or tj's n).

However you can include in your package.json for the project such that it relies on node 5. (Under the "engine" property)

Answer (score 0):

None of the install/rebuild solutions resolved the issue for me (using gulp).

Here is how I resolved it:

1) Download the missing binding file from the [repository](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries).

2) Rename the file `binding.node`.

3) Create `/node-modules/vendor/<operating system>/` (for my version of node/node-sass the `<operating system>` directory for linux is `linux-x64-64`, use folder name from missing binding error message)

4) Add `binding.node` file to `/node-modules/vendor/<operating system>/`.

5) run gulp